# How to remove the rest of a folder path in PHP

Tags: php

i have displayed the follow folders from my ftp it is taking it out correctly but i am trying to display the last folder is there anyway of doing this e.g str_replace but the is not exactly what i am looking for.

```
    httpdocs/user_images/ 
e.g user_images

    httpdocs/user_images/home 
e.g home

    httpdocs/user_images/home/lastest 
e.g lastest

    httpdocs/user_images/home/lastest/monday 
e.g monday

    httpdocs/user_images/home/lastest/friday 
e.g friday
```

Answer (score 4):

[basename](http://php.net/basename)() is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

use preg_split, and array_pop. Sample code:

```
<?php

$dirs = array("httpdocs/user_images/", "httpdocs/user_images/home", "httpdocs/user_images/home/lastest", "httpdocs/user_images/home/lastest/monday","httpdocs/user_images/home/lastest/friday");    
foreach ($dirs as $_) {  
                $bits = preg_split("|/|", $_);
                print $_ . " --> " . array_pop($bits) . "\n";
}
```